# Add simple jquery based See/Hide more action to html data written in ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am in a little trouble here. The solution my be easy but no idea clicked till now. I have a text area to be filled by the user with ckeditor. if incase the text is too long, i used php to split the content before rendering and i would added a see/hide more action using jquery toggle effects. a minor work around may be:

if the text was

```
Appropriate length text here.Other hidden texts here.
```

it would be

```
<div class="show always">Appropriate length text here.</div>
<div class="togglehidden1">See more</div>
<div class="hidefirst" style="display:none">Other hidden texts here.</div>
<div class="togglehidden2" style="display:none">Hide more</div>
```

but the deal here is the ckeditor actually puts a whole lot of html stuffs here, in real the  the string we receive is completely unthinkable of. for e.g.:

```
<div><p><b>Appropriate</b> length text here.</p></div><div>Other hidden texts here.</div>
```

using the same method to split and insert some see more actions then it would be

```
<div class="show always"><div><p><b>Appropriate</b> length</div>
<div class="togglehidden1">See more</div>
<div class="hidefirst" style="display:none">here.</p></div><div>Other hidden texts here.</div></div>
<div class="togglehidden2" style="display:none">Hide more</div>
```

so, only this div is hidden

```
<div class="hidefirst" style="display:none">here.</p></div>
```

and this section here is left seen.

```
<div>Other hidden texts here.</div></div>
```

please suggest. am i doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6Wgv/).

The **HTML** code

```
<div class="show always">
    <div><p><b>Appropriate</b> length here.</p>
        <div class="togglehidden">See more</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hidefirst">
    <div>Other hidden texts here.</div>
</div>
```

The **jQuery** code (using the **slideToggle()** to create an animation)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hide the content when the document is ready
    $('.hidefirst').hide();
    //on clicking the See more/Hide More toggle the visible state of element
    $('.togglehidden').bind('click', function() {
        $('.hidefirst').slideToggle(function() {
            // if element is visible change the text to Hide more
            if ($(this).is(':visible'))
                $('.togglehidden').html('Hide more');
            // else change the text do See more
            else
                $('.togglehidden').html('See more'); 
        });
    });
});
```

1. Bind the click event to the **.togglehidden** class
2. Use the slideToggle() to show/hide the content of **.hidefirst**
3. In the slideToogle callback check if the content is visible and set
   the appropriate message.

Hope it helps.